# .htaccess changes my index to a relative page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

We all know that 
www.somewebsite.com/profile.php?username=1 
 
is not an SEO friendly website,
So I'm writing a .htaccess MODrewrite to make the username variable seem like a $_GET variable of the index file like the the profile.php file was not there at all like 
www.somewebsite.com/speedmon 
 
The code works, only for a glitch, when the user enters somewebsite.com in the browser, it redirects to the profile.php page like it was the index.php file in the first place. Here's my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern **^([a-z0-9]+)?$** matches any chars in the uri ranging from **a** to **z** and **0** to **9** . The problem is that the pattern also matches an empty uri because  of the **?** .  If you omit the ? , your pattern will not match the root directory.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$
```